# MSBuild/TFS Build property for the test results out directory path

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tfs, msbuild

I am running a build using TFS 2008 to build a Visual Studio 2010 solution.  The build is set to run unit tests, and when it does, it creates a folder such as this to hold the test results:

D:\Temp\MyApp\MyApp.Dev\TestResults\MyAccount_MyBuildServerName 2010-07-29 18_07_00_Any CPU_Release\Out\

Is there a built-in property I can use in the TFSBuild.proj file to get the path above?  I would like to reference something like "$(TestResultsOutFolderPath)" in my build file, but I don't know if such a property exists.  So far the only properties I have found only get me to the "TestResults" level and do not add the dynamic folder that contains the timestamp info which I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is no built-in property for that. But, you can create your own property in TFSBuild.proj under the `PropertyGroup` element like

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TestResultsOutFolderPath>...</TestResultsOutFolderPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

you can create the full path by combining the built-in TFS properties
some are listed at [TFS Properties](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/30_useful_team.html)

Comment: I considered this, and I already saw that page (and others, like the one from Aaron Hallberg), but none of them give the dynamic folder that contains the timestamp info, so thus far this approach has not worked.  I'd be happy to combine several properties, but so far I am still missing one critical piece of the path.

Comment: how about the BuildNumber property to get the timestamp? seems it is currently set to that format

Comment: The BuildNumber property does not have the same format.  But in any case, I think it has been long enough that I have to accept the "there is no built-in property for that" answer even if I wish there was one.